# Why does scrolling the page not scroll the cursor trail with the mouse?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm using the same cursor trail that i've found twenty exact copies of all over the internet from cursor script generators. On all of those sites using the same code, when you scroll down the page, the trail will remain by the mouse where it should. But when inside of my code, scrolling down the page leaves the trail at the same position before scrolling and then mouse movement moves the trail that is an inch above the cursor. The trail can never be lower on the page than the bottom of the page on loading. I honeslty just don't understand why this appears to be an isolated case. Any help is appreciated! I use a layout.jsp page to combine my header.jsp + view(content) + footer.jsp. Working with Eclipse EE and tomcat 7 :P

**Header**

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.mouse 
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: -50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
body
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
-->
</style>
<script>
    var x,y
    var step=20
    var doit=0
    var text=" Text.. "
    text=text.split("")

    var xpos=new Array()
    for (i=0;i<=text.length-1;i++) {
    xpos[i]=-50
}

    var ypos=new Array()
    for (i=0;i<=text.length-1;i++) {
    ypos[i]=-50
}

function anddo(e){
    x = (document.layers) ? e.pageX : document.body.scrollLeft+event.clientX
    y = (document.layers) ? e.pageY : document.body.scrollTop+event.clientY
    doit=1
}

function trail() {
    if (doit==1 && document.all) {
        for (i=text.length-1; i>=1; i--) {
            xpos[i]=xpos[i-1]+step
            ypos[i]=ypos[i-1]
        }
        xpos[0]=x+step
        ypos[0]=y

        for (i=0; i<text.length-1; i++) {
            var place = eval("span"+(i)+".style")
            place.posLeft=xpos[i]
            place.posTop=ypos[i]
        }
    }

    else if (doit==1 && document.layers) {
        for (i=text.length-1; i>=1; i--) {
            xpos[i]=xpos[i-1]+step
            ypos[i]=ypos[i-1]
        }
        xpos[0]=x+step
        ypos[0]=y

        for (i=0; i<text.length-1; i++) {
            var place = eval("document.span"+i)
            place.left=xpos[i]
            place.top=ypos[i]
        }
    }
        var timer=setTimeout("trail()",30)
}
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<body onLoad="trail()">

<script>
<!-- Beginning of JavaScript -

for (i=0;i<=text.length-1;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='span"+i+"' class='mouse'>")
    document.write(text[i])
    document.write("</span>")
}

if (document.layers){
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
}
document.onmousemove = anddo;

// - End of JavaScript - -->
</script>


    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/template/header.jsp" />
    <!-- (4)*** Include the Page Content into the template using the JSP Include directive *** -->
    <jsp:include page="<%=content%>" />
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/template/footer.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to clarify when you are talking about positions if they are relative to the mouse position or the page content. It's not clear what you are talking about

Comment: Update - I just searched for my problem in bing instead of google and starting finding actually helpfull info lol Bing right? Crazy! Anways, i understand that this is a really outdated method of creating this effect now :/ Can anyone point me towards a more modern direction?

Comment: a) why in the world are you displaying a cursor trail, and b) posting your entire code file just makes people not want to read it. cut it down to the **relevant** parts.

Comment: I bet that doesn't work in firefox, right? And a "more modern" way of doing a cursor trail would be to not do one at all.

Comment: It only produces the trail in IE. But still doesn't follow down the scrolling on IE.

Comment: sgroves - Does that look better? And i'm in a group working on a class final that we're finished with but just having some fun adding in more and more qwerky functions before we have to sumbit. It's not required to appear professional. :P So this is just something we think would get a few people in class to laugh and so we wanna do it.